# defining mysql table relationships

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables named DrugProd, PlasticProd, FoodProd each with its own set of attributes. I have another table named ProdLot. I want a row attribute in this table to refer to a row (ID) in one of the three tables. What is the best way to identify the table and the ID in a row of ProdLot table. ProdLot table has other columns such as Name, number of items in a lot etc. 
Thank you. 
Girish

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is by adding three columns to `ProdLot`:

- `DrugProdId` which is a foreign key, referencing `DrugProd(Id)`,
- `PlasticProdId` which is a foreign key, referencing `PlasticProd(Id)`, and
- `FoodProdId` which is a foreign key, referencing `FoodProd(Id)`.

Of these three ids, only one will be allowed to be non-null at any given moment.  In your `ProdLot` table definition you can enforce this with a `CHECK` constraint.

This is the best way because it allows your schema to continue being a valid relational database schema in which ***referential integrity*** can still be enforced.

Answer (score 0):

I like to identify foreign keys beginning with the letters "fk" + [name of the table]. That way it will be clear that the field is a foreign key.

So, if you will have a foreign key in ProdLot referencing the primary key of DrugProd, it could be identified as one of the following names:

- fkDrugProd
- FkDrugProd
- fk_drug_prod
- FK_DRUG_PROD

Also, In DrugProd table, I would name the primary key as "id" + [name of table]. For example, choose one of the following:

- idDrugProd
- IdDrugProd
- id_drug_prod
- ID_DRUG_PROD

When you make selects joining with multiples tables, this naming schema will help you avoiding name collisions and to rapidly identify primary keys and foreign keys.